# Connect from plain javascript to socket.io backend? - Connection closed before handshake

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I am trying to connect my client side javascript to a backend websocket service hosted using socket.io .

I am trying to use the native WebSocket object to connect to the socket.io server like :

```
new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080/socket.io/websocket")
```

But I keep getting :

> Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

I have tried connecting using the client side socket.io library just to confirm that the server is up and fine, and this works, but in production I only have the WebSocket object available.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change your url to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/websocket'. Did it work?

Comment: nope it did not work

Answer (score 0):

`wss` is for secure web socket, I assume you are not using ssl cerificate in localhost
so

```
new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/websocket")
```

will work.

**Edit:** 
When you use socket.io client, you will be using

`var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');`

to use url with `WebSocket` you need `ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?transport=websocket`

```
new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?transport=websocket')
```

Comment: I am using https on my server and I can connect to the https endpoint just fine through the browser to see if my server is online, I can also connect to the wss endpoint with the client of socket.io but I cant initialize the WebSocket object, doing exactly what you said using wss gives me an error that the connection was closed before receiving a handshake response.

Comment: Check if edited answer works for you, assuming you are not using `wss` in localhost